# Django project - quiz Error 405 while clicking on + on the website

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am writing an newbie application - newbie quiz for learning programming languages.
I am getting this message:
[image: Error gotten]

#views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from .models import Question


# Create your views here.
class QuestionView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            print('Received data:', request.POST['itemName'])
            Question.objects.create(name = request.POST['itemName'])
        all_items = Question.objects.all() #Access to items from database Nur 1 .get(id=1); .filter(name='Hello')
        return render(request, "questionmanager.html", {'all_items': all_items})
```

#models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    created_at=models.DateField(default=date.today)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    done=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

#HTML - here questions/ items can be added

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
                background-color: rgba(179, 241, 245, 0.1);
                margin: 0;
            }
            header {
                background-color: rgba(142, 250, 184, 0.05);
                display: flex;
                padding-left: 20px;
                box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            }
            button {
                height: 60px;
                width: 60px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                background-color: rgba(163, 122, 11);
                border: unset;
                font-size: 35px;
                color: rgba(31, 28, 20);
                position: absolute;
                right: 16px;
                bottom: 16px;
            }
            .list-item {
                background-color: #9effff;
                height: 60px;
                box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
                padding-left: 20px;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Questions</h1>
        </header>
        {% for row in all_items %} <!-- row from database- all data will be shown -->
        <div class="list-item"><input type="checkbox" /> {{ row.name }}</div>
        {% endfor %}

        <div class="list-item"><input type="checkbox" /> TestQQQQuestion</div>
        <button onclick="addQuestion()">+</button>
        <script>
            function addQuestion(){
                let itemName = prompt('Add new question');
                let token = "{{ csrf_token }}";
                let formData=new FormData();
                formData.append('itemName', itemName);
                formData.append("csrfmiddlewaretoken", token);

                fetch('/question/', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData
                });
                window.location.reload(); <!-- Refreshing the website to get the items/questions visible -->
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from Learntest.views import QuestionView

urlpatterns = [path("admin/", admin.site.urls), path("question/", QuestionView.as_view(), name="question")]
```

They never get added with Plus button and 405 appears. The test question is added in the code. I am learning and might make silly mistakes :)
[image: Page view]

I followed a similar code for similar purpose.

Comment: You have only added a `get` method, but no `post` method in your view.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it might work?

```js
<script>
    function addQuestion() {
        let itemName = prompt('Add new question');
        let token = "{{ csrf_token }}";
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('itemName', itemName);
        formData.append("csrfmiddlewaretoken", token);

        fetch('/question/', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            headers: {
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', // Add this header to specify AJAX request
            },
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                window.location.reload(); // Refresh the website on success
            } else {
                alert('Failed to add question');
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            alert('An error occurred while adding the question');
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [@marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4151233/marco) comment, since you are using a classed-based view you need to define the HTTP method separately

```py
class QuestionListView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        all_items = Question.objects.all()  # Retrieve all items from the database
        return render(request, "questionmanager.html", {'all_items': all_items})

    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            print('Received data:', request.POST['itemName'])
            Question.objects.create(name=request.POST['itemName'])
        return redirect('question-list')
```

For more details refer to [Django Documentation for class-based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/).